# Xcode 4 Hangs on Exception

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4

I'm running my app in Xcode 4 using the simulator.  Whenever an exception is thrown and the debugger shows me the line at which it crashed, Xcode wont allow me to kill the app.  I can edit my code, even rebuild it, but I can't terminate the current run.  I have been killing Xcode all together and restarting, but there has to be something I'm missing, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i first downloaded Xcode it did the same thing to me but a clean Re- Install fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you go to the debugger console and enter "kill"? It should ask you to confirm that you want to kill the running inferior process, and once you confirm that, the inferior (the application it's debugging) should be murdered.